# Readings on how macro economic policies change with size of countries

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

I have developed an intuition that the type of economic policies which would be suitable for countries, would change with respect to the size of countries. For example, the ideal fiscal policy, for a big country, say China, would be fundamnetally different from a fiscal policy, for a small country like Switzerland.

Could someone suggest me books I could read to learn more about this topic?

---

[Related](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52869/how-does-macroeconomics-change-as-state-size-of-a-country-varies?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C54.4762)